# Delphi TClientDataSet Filtering using LIKE and foCaseInsensitive

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, tclientdataset

Using Delphi XE, I'm trying to do some filtering on a TClientDataSet and I'm unable to get the case-insensitive filtering to work properly in conjunction with a LIKE operator

Consider this code which does the filtering

```
cdsDocs.DisableControls;
try
  cdsDocs.Filtered := False;
  cdsDocs.FilterOptions := [foCaseInsensitive];
  cdsDocs.Filter := 'Product LIKE ''%' + txtFilter.Text + '%''';
  cdsDocs.Filtered := True;
finally
  cdsDocs.EnableControls;
end;
```

and consider that the Product field of this dataset contains only the values 'b' and 'B'.

1. when (txtFilter.Text = 'b') I only get 'b's (I'm expecting 'b's and 'B's)
2. when (txtFilter.Text = 'B') I only get 'B's (likewise, I'm expecting 'b's and 'B's)

It seems as though the LIKE '%b%' and the foCaseInsensitive don't work together? What should I do to make it work? I read the documentation but I can't find my mistake (if any). TIA.

Comment: It looks ok for me. Otherwise you can also use TClientDataSet event OnFilterRecords, where you can set if certain record is visible.

Comment: It's quite interesting, the filter only won't apply if the text to search (caseinsensitive) is isimilar to the fields content. A workaround could be `.Filter := 'Text  LIKE ''%' + TextFilter.Text + '%'' or Text=' + QuotedStr(textFilter.Text);`

Comment: @bummi Thanks. Are you saying that you were able to reproduce my problem?

Comment: Yes, the shown workaround would fix it for me.

Comment: @bummi I doubt it would work if I use real product names (longer than 1 char). I fear there is a bug in XE, or worse in my code (quelle horreur!)

Comment: I agree with supposing it a bug, I tried above with diffent combinations and found it working, but you are right, it's not a  
satisfying solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything was working fine until I tried to extend the filtering to allow for case-insensitive searches (I tried to use the existing FilterOption foCaseInsensitive), now suddenly I have a bug? No, that doesn't make sense to me. I've decided to achieve the desired case-insensitive filtering another way, and keep my ego intact.

Here's the revised code (works perfectly)

```
cdDocs.DisableControls;
try
  cdDocs.Filtered := False;
  cdDocs.FilterOptions := [];

  if (cbCaseSensitive.Checked) then
    cdDocs.Filter := 'Product LIKE ''%' + txtFilter.Text + '%'''
  else
    cdDocs.Filter := 'UPPER(Product) LIKE ''%' + UPPERCASE(txtFilter.Text) + '%''';

  cdDocs.Filtered := True;
finally
  cdDocs.EnableControls;
end;
```

BTW, this is connecting to an Interbase/Firebird database using the Interbase DB Access components that ship with Delphi XE. If connecting to a different DB you *may* need to replace the "UPPER" function with the equivalent function for your chosen RDBMS (whatever you would use in the equivalent SQL WHERE clause)

Comment: thanks for this, but in my case (ibdac TIBCTable with firebird 2.5.2) i get following exception : "field UPPER not found"...  whatever i do : "(UPPER(UTF8 Product collate fr_fr) LIKE ''%'+str+'%'')" upper not found too. It seems it rejects me from using any operations on fields...