# Filter ClientDataSet

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a delphi form which has a cxGrid on it. This grid is populating records via a clientdataset.

Typing into a tedit box and clicking a button, I would like to be able to filter the grid to display records from what is entered into the tedit box.

So far I have this but it doesn't pull back any records.

```
dmodule.cds.DisableControls;
try
  dmodule.cds.Filtered := False;
  dmodule.cds.FilterOptions := [];

  dmodule.cds.Filter := 'Field LIKE''%' + editSearch.Text+ '%''';

  dmodule.cds.Filtered := True;
finally
  dmodule.cds.EnableControls;
end;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Is there a blank between LIKE and the apostrophe? I assume "Field" is the name of the field to filter.

Comment: There is no blank between them and yes the word 'Field' is what to filter

Comment: Do you get the result you're expecting if you disconnect your cxGrid from the datasource and connect a TDBGrid to it instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17780969/delphi-tclientdataset-filtering-using-like-and-focaseinsensitive

Comment: @Dag: Just an advice: **do not** access the dataset in the DataModule directly. Instead, declare a method named (for instance) `FilterByField` in you DataModule and call it. By doing this you hide the internals of your class from your form, what increases your code quality

Comment: Your code works fine for me, so I suspect your cxGrid isn't properly configured.  Try substituting a TDBGrid like I suggested.  Also, add a line "Caption := IntToStr(dmodule.cds.RecordCount);" to the end of your routine.

Comment: I have tried dbGrid and still no result, I get 0 records back

Comment: Are you 100% positive that there are records in the CDS which match your filter criterion?  Also, what is the datatype of your Field field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try these simple changes below:

```
dmodule.cds.FilterOptions := [foCaseInsensitive,foNoPartialCompare];
dmodule.cds.Filter := 'Field LIKE '+ QuotedStr('%'+ editSearch.Text + '%');
```

I've tested here with a cxGrid and it worked fine.

Comment: Sorry, I've downvoted your q because, like I said in comments, your original code worked perfectly well when I tested it with a TcxGrid and a TDBGrid one.  Therefore, if this answer fixed your problem, it is because what was causing it was something not mentioned in your q, like the specific data you were testing against.  So, please re-trace your steps and add to your q what was *actually* causing your prob.